# Creating a landing page that redirects to another page but does pre-defined calls/actions on Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have Dashboard component which has some children components like CampaignNotification.

CampaignNotification has also its own children components. In this campaignNotification, there are some buttons that triggers some actions.

I need to create a landing page that goes (or show) dashboard, but will call some methods of children components of the CampaignNotification. This landing page will have all needed parameters. e.g: `/redirect/campaign_id=1&action_type=approve`

For instance a modal which is opened by a button will be opened automatically.

The only way that I found is defining refs for each child and call them in the redirect page, but `this.$refs.Dashboard.$refs.CampaignNotification.$refs` is `undefined`. (`this.$refs.Dashboard` is fine, but `this.$refs.Dashboard.$refs` is empty)

I can not reach child of another child via `$refs`. If it had worked, it'd be still a headache to play with it. Would it be a better way to achieve my goal? It is doable if I put this pre-defined action list in the child component, but I also want to make it decoupled and create a generic system that I can create pre-defined action lists and run them by another custom link with parameters.

Comment: When are you calling the methods?  Can you put a `setTimeout` in a `mounted()` hook and see if the `$ref` population is just delayed?  I sometimes have issues where a component hasn't fully populated all the references before trying to reach for them.

Comment: I think you want to put the methods that share functionality in a mixin and then import that mixin from within your child component and your Dashboard component. The Dashbaord component can have the logic based on the URL, the child component can have the button trigger.

Comment: @zero298 just tried it and it finds the name of child ref, but it's value is undefined. I get something like that: {refName: undefined}

Comment: @MatthiasS If I create mixin and use it in the child component I want to run actions, how will I trigger it in the top parent, Dashboard?

Comment: You could make use of Vuex. Commiting a state mutation that your children component would watch and trigger his method from that ? The point of modern framework is to get rid of direct DOM manipulation. You should try to use Vue's reactivity system for that.